# how to get value of input text type in mulitpart form

Tags: java, file-upload

I've read and followed an example file uploading via commons-fileupload api. It works when I post a file, but when I include normal fields like input type="text" it seems like values of field name comes as null. In this case field name as email. Here is a code I am using. Hope experienced eyes of developers out there can point out to me what I am doing wrong. Thank you and have a blessed day!

#### code in servlet class

```
        try {                           
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

            for (FileItem item : items) {
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    if(item.getFieldName().equals("email")) { 
                        payLoad.append("&email=" +   item.getString());

                }
                else         {                                              
                    encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(item.get()));                
                    payLoad.append("&content=" + encodedBase64);
                }
            }
            payLoad = payLoad.deleteCharAt(0); // payLoad = new StringBuffer()
```

Comment: In the `<form>` are you using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? You need to make sure that the form has that attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your reply back. Yes, I used enctype="multipart/form-data". I realized my problem actually. Above code works. My mistake was before I posted it, I changed from item.getFieldName() == "email" to item.getFieldName().equals("email").

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code (this code work fine for me)

```
private Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
for(FileItem item: items){
   if (!item.isFormField()) {
    ...
   } else{
     String field = item.getFieldName();
     String content = item.getString();
     parameterMap.put(field,new String[]{content});
   }
 }
```

Then you can print all the content of parameterMap, 
I think your form field have a name other than "email"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please look at the comment I replied back to Marcelo. Sorry about not being clear in my question (it was my first one). else statement handles input type="file" where !item.isFormField() condition meets. I had a trouble with if statement where it handles input type=text|radio|etc.